# Don't laugh, but I can't get a font to show up on my .html file (masOS Catalina)

Tags: html, css, fonts

Im trying to apply 'Microgramma' to my logo in. the navbar. What am I doing wrong,? It's install on my computer and in the correct file. Confident I'm doing everything right!

codepen.io/daddchamploo/pen/ZEWNvXN

Comment: Hi DADD, welcome to SO. Can you host your complete file/folder setup to any online editor(JSfiddle, codepen & etc). Moreover you need to embed the custom font in CSS and then call the font in the css style(div.logo). You havent mentioned font-family in css.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the font family first then only font will work for your .html page.

Syntax:

```
 @font-face{
      font-family:'you font name';
      src:url('your font path');
 }
```

Example:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:helvetica;
    src:url(../fonts/helvetica-normal.ttf);
}
```

Then You can add font in your CSS like:

```
div.logo {
    font-family: helvetica;
}
```

Add it like this and everything will be working correctly.

Comment: Okay. I did just as you said and it still wont work. I even did it using helvetica and it was successful but for some reason not this font. https://codepen.io/daddchamploo/pen/ZEWNvXN

Answer (score 0):

Looks you have included the wrong font file name

```css
div.logo{
    width: 180px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family:"Michroma";
}
```